# Drag and drop html data in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui

I'm having a normal html section where I'm dropping some html code. I need them to append after the class `.page-content-wrapper` if there is no item and if there is item I want to append the html code below the very last element and each element is sortable. I'm pulling out the html code through my php function in JSON format while taking it to console.log I get:

```
Object {htmlcode: "<div>//html code....</div>"}
```

I've already passed `datatype` to be `json` in `ajax request` I'm just pulling out the data to the droppable section so that I can append to the last element in the droppable zone. where I'm simply returning the value to a variable and trying to append it in the droppable element. Following is my JQuery:

```
 var nitsbuilder = {
    nits_id: $('[data-nitsid]'),
    editarea: $('.page-content-wrapper')
};

 nitsbuilder.dropeventhandler = function (nits_id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: dropurl,
        data: { nits_id: nits_id, _token: token},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            return(data);
        }
    });
}

nitsbuilder.init = function () {
    var navmenu= $('ul.nitseditormenu').find('li').find('ul').find('li');
    var origin= 'sortable';
    navmenu.draggable({
        connectToSortable: "nitsbuilder.editarea",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move",
        start: function () {
            origin = 'draggable';
        }
    });

    nitsbuilder.editarea.droppable({
       drop: function (event, ui) {
                var nits_id = ui.draggable.data('nitsid');
                code = nitsbuilder.dropeventhandler(nits_id);
                console.log(code);
            if(origin === 'draggable'){
                ui.draggable.html(code);
                origin= 'sortable';
            }
       }
    }).sortable({
        revert: true
    });
}();
```

`Console.log` in droppable section displays undefined. I'm stuck with these, help me out guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `nitsbuilder.dropeventhandler` function execute an ajax call you get nothing as return value even if you wrote retun inside success part of ajax call.

Normally, you may proceed in a lot of different ways. My way to address this is using callbacks:

when the function finishes it executes my callback with the right data.

So I suggest you to rearrange your code in this way:

```
 nitsbuilder.dropeventhandler = function (nits_id, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: dropurl,
            data: { nits_id: nits_id, _token: token},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                //-----------------------------------
                // instead of :
                // return(data);
                callback(data);

                //-----------------------------------
            }
        });
    }
```

Add a new function (callback) like:

```
function myfunc(code) {
            console.log(code);
            if(origin === 'draggable'){
                ui.draggable.html(code);
                origin= 'sortable';
            }
        }
```

And then the final part:

```
nitsbuilder.editarea.droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var nits_id = ui.draggable.data('nitsid');

                 // use the callback function added to your object
                 nitsbuilder.dropeventhandler(nits_id, myfunc);
            }
        }).sortable({
            revert: true
        });
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but when I break like this I get an undefined reference error for `ui` at `ui.draggable` in `myfunc` section

Comment: @NitishKumar Sorry, my answer is only a way to describe you the strategy. In the callback function you need to add "event, ui" parameters you have in the droppable -- drop event. I hope this can help you. Let me know.